# Mongoose: Filter nested documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a MongoDB collection with documents that follows this shape:

```
"peopleList": [
 {
  "_id": "List 1 id",
  "name": "List 1",
  "people": [
    {
      "_id": "A Person id",
      "name": "A Person",
      "email": "person@email.com"
    },
    {  
      "_id": "Another Person id",
      "name": "Another Person",
      "email": "another.person@email.com"
    },
  ],
 },
 {
  "_id": "List 2 id",
  "name": "List 2",
  "people": [
    {
      "_id": "A Person id",
      "name": "A Person",
      "email": "person@email.com"
    },
  ],
 }
]
```

As you can see, the same Person object can appear in multiple lists.

So what I want is to retrieve all lists that a given person is part.

For e.g:

```
Passing _id: "A Person id" -> the query should return List 1 and List 2,

Passing _id: "Another Person id:" -> the query should return only List 1.
```

I tried this query:

```
await PeopleList.find({ people: { _id: 'A person id' } });
```

But the query returned an empty array, even 'A person id' is a document present in many lists.

**EDIT**

Sharing the Fahad answer, the correct query is:

```
await PeopleList.find({
  people: { $elemMatch: { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId('A person id') } 
}});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume that your `mongo schema` name is `PeopleList` so your filter query will be like this

```
PeopleList.find({people : {$elemMatch:{_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId('321321321321321')}});
```

For more info you can see documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/)

Comment: It doesn't work. By inseting {people._id: "A person id"} , the application crashes due Parsing error.

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ","

Comment: The precise query I did was: 
lists = await PeopleList.find({ people._id : authorId }).select([
      '-__v',
      '-updatedAt',
      '-createdAt'
    ]);

Comment: just remove `.select`  and all that for the time being after .find() and try updated query.

Comment: In your `authorId ` can you tell what's in that `authorId` ? and also please add your tried query code in your question post so that i can make sure that your are trying the right thing or not

Comment: authorId is a valid person object Id. I also tried to hardcode a manual string id once to test it. And it didn't work too.

Comment: You have to caste your `_id(string)` into type of `ObjectId(mongoose.Types.ObjectId)`

Comment: I did it already. I also tried to get the full author object and pass author._id. It also returned an empty array.

Comment: Sorry still not working: 

const lists = await PeopleList.find({
      people: { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5e1fbd7a8c3f315558fd380b') },
    });

Comment: This is not my updated answer. Check updated answer

Comment: It worked with $elemMatch! I just had to cast the object id. But worked! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `$elemMatch` and `$in` to find in array. So try like this

```
 "people": { $elemMatch: { "_id": { $in: [mongoose.Types.ObjectId(params.id) ] } } }
```

Comment: Thank you Gandhi! It worked. I marked Fahad's answer since he answered first. But thank you a lot.